# Commutative rings in which every their subgroup is subring or ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, principal-ideal-domains

We are interested in commutative rings $(R,+,\cdot)$ such that:

(a) All subgroups are ideals;

(b) All subgroups are subrings;

(c) All subrings are ideals.

For example $(\mathbb{Z},+,\cdot)$ and $((\mathbb{Z}_n,+,\cdot)$ enjoy
all the properties. Now,

(1) Are these true for all PID's?, what about UFD's?

**(2)** Can somebody state some **classes of such rings**?

Comment: As for (2), it would be important to know wether you consider non-unital rings.

Comment: We can consider the two cases (unital and non-unital) separately.

Comment: For unital rings $R$ there is a straightforward fact: consider the subgroup of $R$ generated by its unit $1$. This is a cyclic group and a subring as well (this holds for any ring). But the only ideal of $R$ contining $1$ is $R$ itself: hence if any subgroup is an ideal, then $R$ must be $\Bbb{Z}$ or $\Bbb{Z}_n$.

Answer (score 2):

> 1) Are these true for all PID's?, what about UFD's?

$\mathbb Q[x]$ is a counterexample for all three points. $\mathbb Q$ is a subgroup and subring that isn't an ideal. And also $\mathbb Q+x\mathbb Q$ is a subgroup, but it isn't a subring. Since none of these are true for all PIDs, then none of these are true for all UFDs.

As mentioned in the comments already, $\mathbb Z$ and its quotients are the only rings with identity in which all subgroups/subrings are ideals. I am not sure what conditions would make subgroups subrings.

Comment: Thanks rschwieb, what about (2)?